# How do I change the color of icon of the selected tab of TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-tablayout

I'm using a `TabLayout` with a `ViewPager` and I'm wondering how I can most efficiently change the color of the icon of the selected tab in the TabLayout.

A perfect reference for how this is implemented is **Google's Youtube app**. On the main page, there are four icons that are colored dark gray. When a specific tab is selected, the tab's icon becomes white.

**Without any third party libraries**, how can I achieve the same effect?

**One possible solution is apparently with selectors.** But in that case, I would have to find both a white and a gray version of the icon and then switch the icon when the tab becomes selected or deselected. I'm wondering if there's a more effective method where I can just highlight the icon color or something. I haven't been able to find this in any tutorial.

**EDIT**

The solution that I mention directly above requires the use of two drawables for each tab's icon. I'm wondering if there's a way I can do it programmatically with **ONE** drawable for each tab's icon.

Comment: Please only use `android-studio` tag if it is specific to the IDE.

Comment: could you find a way to solve this using only one drawable? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 101):

I found a way that can be easy.

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
            new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {

                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    super.onTabSelected(tab);
                    int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabSelectedIconColor);
                    tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    super.onTabUnselected(tab);
                    int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabUnselectedIconColor);
                    tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    super.onTabReselected(tab);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: can u pls tell i tried to follow same way but unfortunately my onTabSelected is not getting called while its calling viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener

Comment: I don't know why onTabSelected is not being called, but I can recommend you make a code debug to know where is the problem. If you definitely don't find the mistake I guess that you can achieve the same with setOnPageChangeListener, but it could be harder to do.

Comment: setOnTabSelectedListener  is deprecated, Use addOnTabSelectedListener

Comment: hi , i  m using customView for tablayout but failed to change icon's color and view backgorund color on tab selection using customView ? Any idea how will i do ?

Answer (score 86):

This can be done very simply, entirely in xml.

Add one line to your TabLayout in your xml, `app:tabIconTint="@color/your_color_selector"`, as below:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabIconTint="@color/your_color_selector"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/selected_color"/>
```

Then, create a color selector file (named "your_color_selector.xml" above) in res/color directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/selected_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/unselected_color"/>
</selector>
```

This assumes you have 2 colors, "selected_color" and "unselected_color" in your colors.xml file.

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    It works
} else {
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/36161252/8072092
}

Comment: @joonsoo it works on versions lower than 23. I'm using in projects down to API 19.

Comment: and where/how do you set the icons that will be changing the color? I use "app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"" and this doesn't work with the color changing.

Comment: for me `state_enabled` worked, yet `state_selected` did not

Answer (score 45):

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: İt worked fine at the beginning bt when you close and open application first ona starts wth the color you gave.

Comment: To prevent this you can call `setCurrentItem(0)` on instance of viewPager from activity when `onBackButton()` method is invoked, and user will always be returned on first fragment when he tries to exit from app.

Comment: you can use tab.getIcon().clearColorFilter(); to remove filter

Comment: setOnTabSelectedListener got deprecated. Use addOnTabSelectedListener instead. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#addOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)

Answer (score 40):

You can use a ColorStateList.

First, create an xml file (e.g. `/color/tab_icon.xml`) that looks like this and defines the different tints for different states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/icon_light"
        android:state_selected="true" />

    <item android:color="@color/icon_light_inactive" />
</selector>
```

Then add this to your code:

```
ColorStateList colors;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    colors = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_icon, getTheme());
}
else {
    colors = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_icon);
}

for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    Drawable icon = tab.getIcon();

     if (icon != null) {
        icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, colors);
    }
}
```

First, you grab the ColorStateList from your XML (the method without theme is deprecated, but necessary for pre-Marshmallow devices). Then you set for each tab's icon it's TintList to the ColorStateList; use DrawableCompat (support library) to support older versions as well.

That's it!

Comment: this is the best solution so far, as it doesn´t imply to manually change the icon color

Comment: I don't, but you only have to insert the latter code in your activity's onCreate(..) method after the TabLayout (named `tabLayout`) has been initialized.

Comment: Can we apply this to a svg icon file?

Comment: You can't use svg in Android at all (without additional libraries), but my solution does also work with [Android Vector Drawables](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#VectorDrawables) (which have similar advantages like svg).

Comment: Your solution works but not for below android 23, all tabs end up having same color and it's the inactive color. Any thoughts why or a workaround??

Comment: Nice solution, but UNFORTUNATELY it does not work for android below 23

Comment: This stopped working for me across all Android API levels since support library 28.0.0.

Answer (score 17):

For it You'll have to customize tab icons using selector class for each Tab like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/advisory_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/advisory_normal" android:state_selected="false" />
```

Comment: So with this method, it's the same as the one described in the question? I'll have to find two drawables for each tab's icon that I have in the layout (one of each color)?

Comment: exactly. For more clarification edit your question with code.

Answer (score 14):

Add this under `res > colors` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>
  <item android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
</selector>
```

Add code in tab view in xml:

```
app:tabIconTint="@color/selector_tab"
```

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    It works
} else {
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/36161252/8072092
}

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use icon fonts (like font awesome) for your icons? then change the font of tab text to your desirable font icon .ttf and enjoy change selected text color to your tab icons!

I, myself, used this method and it is really nice and clean :)

firstly, set up the titles from your desired icon font:

in string.xml:

```
    <string name="ic_calculator">&#xf1ec;</string>
    <string name="ic_bank">&#xf19c;</string>
```

then in MainActivity.Java:

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentBank(), getString(R.string.ic_bank));
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentCalculate(), getString(R.string.ic_calculator));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Then you should change the font of Tab titles to font-awesome:

```
    Typeface typeFaceFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(typeFaceFont);
            }
        }
    }
```

and last but not least, in your related .xml file, set color for your tabTextColor and tabSelectedTextColor:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

and in colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="colorHighlight">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#E1E3F3</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Icon fonts do not work on some devices. Please use with caution.

Answer (score 5):

check the following code. Customise your icon one is color and another one is no color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mybookings_select" android:state_selected="true"/><!-- tab is selected(colored icon)-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mybookings" /><!-- tab is not selected(normal no color icon)-->
```

Answer (score 4):

For change tint even you can set same color what ever you drawble tab icon have

```
   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:background="@color/bgFrag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabTextColor="@drawable/tab_search_text_clr"
                app:tabIconTintMode="multiply"
                app:tabIconTint="#ffffff"
                app:tabIndicator="@null"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabInlineLabel="true"
                app:tabMode="fixed" >

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

> tab_search_text_clr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>  <!-- checked -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>  <!-- checked -->
    <item android:color="#acacac"/><!-- anything else -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit old, but I was just facing the same issue and it seems that the answers here are outdated.

Use a color state list and add it directly to the TabLayout XML element

Given the tab_icon.xml file below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</selector>
```

And the TabLayout XML element (notice the **tabIconTint** attr)

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/favourites_selectionTL"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIconTint="@color/tab_icon"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

On reference to the second answer which shows how to set color separately, many people might be wondering around how to remove the color of the first icon while switching to next one. What you can do is go like this :

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //for removing the color of first icon when switched to next tab
        tablayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().clearColorFilter();
        //for other tabs
        tab.getIcon().clearColorFilter();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});}
```

**I would have commented on the second answer but did not have enough reputations for that! Sorry. But please follow that you'd save your time and your headache! Happy learning**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `addOnTabSelectedListener`, it works for me.

```
tablayout = findViewById(R.id.viewall_tablayout);
pager = findViewById(R.id.viewall_pager);
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragments(new RestFragment(),"Restaurant");
adapter.addFragments(new BarFragment(),"Bar");
adapter.addFragments(new HotelFragment(),"Hotel");
adapter.addFragments(new CoffeeFragment(),"Coffee Shop");
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
tablayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

tablayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_restaurant);
tablayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_glass_and_bottle_of_wine);
tablayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_hotel_black_24dp);
tablayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_hot_coffee);

tablayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent,getTheme()));
tablayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent,getTheme()));
tablayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent,getTheme()));
tablayout.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent,getTheme()));
tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tab.getIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary,getTheme()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tab.getIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent,getTheme()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ColorStateList` only has two entries: [`android.R.attr.state_selected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#state_selected) and the default wildcard. These can be defined eg. with `src/main/res/xml/tab_layout_color_state.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Then `R.xml.tab_layout_color_state` can be applied as a `ColorStateList`:

```
private void applyColorStateList(@NonNull TabLayout tabLayout, int resId) {
    tabLayout.setTabIconTint(requireContext().getColorStateList(resId));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way of "Highlighting" the icon is to access the image view and set the color filter. Try using the setColorFilter(int color) ImageView method and applying the color white.

Comment: yes but how can we access imageview when tab is selected

Answer (score 2):

`tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {...}`
Has been deprecated. Rather Use

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabSelectedIconColor);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabUnselectedIconColor);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Extending my prefered answer with the ColorStateList from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36161252/2080959), you can use the following solution if you are using custom tabs.

Set up tabs in your activity's xml

```
 ...

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/nav_bar_tab_item"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/nav_bar_tab_item"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

...
```

And custom tab layout nav_bar_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/nav_bar_item_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"

<!-- Use selector here to change the text color when selected/unselected -->
    android:textColor="@color/nav_bar_icons_color"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_img"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your activity

```
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_tablayout);

    ConstraintLayout navMyHotelLayout = (ConstraintLayout) tabLayout.getTabAt(0)
            .getCustomView();
    tab1Icon = navMyHotelLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
    tab1TextView = navMyHotelLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

    tab1Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tab1);

    // Use the selector here to change the color when selected/unselected
    tintImageViewSelector(tab1Icon, R.color.nav_bar_icons_color);

    tab1TextView.setText("tab 1");

    ConstraintLayout navTtdLayout = (ConstraintLayout) tabLayout.getTabAt(1)
            .getCustomView();
    tab2Icon = navTtdLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
    tab2View = navTtdLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

    tab2Icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tab2);
    tintImageViewSelector(tab2Icon, R.color.nav_bar_icons_color);
    tab2TextView.setText("tab 2");
```

And add these helper functions for the change of color

```
public static void tintDrawableSelector(Drawable vd, final @ColorRes int clrRes, Context context) {

    DrawableCompat.setTintList(vd, ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, clrRes));
}

public static void tintImageViewSelector(ImageView imgView, final @ColorRes int clrRes, Context context) {

    tintDrawableSelector(imgView.getDrawable(), clrRes);
}
```

Finally, the selector nav_bar_icons_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the following code:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons1[0]);
        }
        if(tab.getPosition() == 1){
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons1[1]);
        }
        if(tab.getPosition() == 2){
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons1[2]);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
});
```

Comment: This ain't working with Material theme like Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight

Answer (score -1):

You can change the text color of selected tab using the following xml attribute of Tab layout :

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="your desired color"
```

To customize your icon color of selected tab you need to use selector
Create a xml file under drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="selected_item_color" android:state_activated="true" />
   <item android:color="unselected_item_color" />
</selector>
```

and add this selector to tab layout xml attribute like below:

```
app:tabIconTint="@drawable/name_of_file"
```

Comment: Does not work. As an aside from not working, if your name_of_file is drawable/name_of_file.xml, you should mark it as such, otherwise you leave the reader to guess what you mean.

Comment: name_of_file is the indication to the reader about the name of their own drawable file.

Answer (score -1):

### Perform the following steps respectively.

app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml (Add to colors.xml)

```
<color name="icon_enabled">#F3D65F</color>
<color name="icon_disabled">#FFFFFF</color>
```

app/src/main/res/color/custom_tab_icon.xml  (Create a folder named color in res. Create a custom tab icon.xml in the folder.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:color="@color/icon_enabled" android:state_selected="true"/>
 <item android:color="@color/icon_disabled" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_action_settings.png (Create)

double click on action_settings to add

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="21.6"
android:viewportHeight="21.6"
android:tint="@color/custom_tab_icon">
<group android:translateX="-1.2"
  android:translateY="-1.2">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
 android:pathData="M19.1,12.9a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,0.1 -0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 -0.1,-0.9l2.1,-1.6a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.1 -0.6L19.4,5.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.6 -0.2l-2.4,1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,-1.6 -0.9l-0.4,-2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 -0.4H10.1a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,-0.5 0.4L9.3,5.4a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,-1.7 0.9l-2.4,-1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,-0.5 0.2l-2,3.4c-0.1,0.2 0,0.4 0.2,0.6l2,1.6a2.8,2.8 0,0 0,-0.1 0.9,2.8 2.8,0 0,0 0.1,0.9L2.8,14.5a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,-0.1 0.6l1.9,3.4a0.7,0.7 0,0 0,0.6 0.2l2.4,-1a6.5,6.5 0,0 0,1.6 0.9l0.4,2.6a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 0.4h3.8a0.5,0.5 0,0 0,0.5 -0.4l0.3,-2.6a5.6,5.6 0,0 0,1.7 -0.9l2.4,1a0.4,0.4 0,0 0,0.5 -0.2l2,-3.4c0.1,-0.2 0,-0.4 -0.2,-0.6ZM12,15.6A3.6,3.6 0,1 1,15.6 12,3.6 3.6,0 0,1 12,15.6Z"/>
</group>
</vector>
```