# selected Tab with elevation

Tags: android, material-design, android-sdk-2.3

I want to show selected tab in this manner can anyone give me idea how to do selected tab up and highlighted like camera in the image

[image: Tab Image in this camera is a selected state]

Comment: Refer this answer.
This may help you [clickhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562117/how-do-i-change-color-of-icon-of-the-selected-tab-of-tablayout)

Comment: Here is exact what u want https://github.com/thelong1EU/SpaceTabLayout

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source libraries available on GIT but none of them will give you the exact thing you want.You have to alter them according to your need.Two libraries which are very near to your requirement are mentioned below:

https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Try using it and mark this answer up if this helps.