# Java android change color tab selected tab

Tags: java, android, tabs

I want to change a background color tab selected. I want change a color background my tab on green when is selected and changed a color  background unselected tab to #a8a8a8

But when I swipe in logs I see this :

```
 Process: pl.smok, PID: 28410


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setColorFilter(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at pl..smok.ui.activity.MainActivity$2.onTabUnselected(MainActivity.java:163)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabUnselected(TabLayout.java:1163)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1149)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1124)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1419)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1524)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is full code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.view_pager)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @BindView(R.id.tab_layout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    ActionBar actionBar;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    int choose;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sp = getSharedPreferences("pfref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sp.edit();
        choose = sp.getInt("screen", 1);
//        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
//        Log.e( "Token: ", token);
        if(choose == 1 )
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        else
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        hideActionBar();

        String[] tabs = {"start", "status", "wiadomości", "nowa wiadomość"};
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabs));

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

            @Override
         public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
             }

            @Override
         public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          CommonUtil.hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
                  }

         @Override
         public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
           });
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
        }

        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.top_bar_container, new TopBarFragment(), TopBarFragment.class.getName())
                .commit();

        processIntent(getIntent());
        createTabIcons();
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        choose = sp.getInt("screen", 1);

        if(choose == 1 )
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        else
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {


//        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
//                tab.getIcon().mutate().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                Log.e("tab count " , tab.getPosition() + " " );
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
//                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        App.getBus().register(this);
        runServices();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        App.getBus().unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        processIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getIntExtra(Const.KEY_GOTO, 0) == 1 && viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onPermissionRequestedEvent(PermissionRequestedEvent event) {
        PermissionUtil.getPermission(this, event.getPermission());
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onPermissionGrantedEvent(PermissionGrantedEvent event) {
        if (event.getPermission().equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            runLocationService();
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onPageNavigateEvent(PageNavigateEvent event) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (event.getPage()) {
            case Const.APP_SETTINGS_LOCATION:
                CommonUtil.hideKeyboard(this);
                intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case Const.PAGE_START:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                break;
            case Const.PAGE_STATUSES:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                break;
            case Const.PAGE_MESSAGES:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                break;
            case Const.PAGE_SEND_MESSAGE:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true)
    public void onLoggedOutEvent(LoggedOutEvent event) {
        String user = Hawk.get(HawkConst.LOGIN_USER);
        String company = Hawk.get(HawkConst.LOGIN_COMPANY);
        String password = Hawk.get(HawkConst.LOGIN_PASSWORD);
        Hawk.clear();
        Hawk.put(HawkConst.LOGIN_USER, user);
        Hawk.put(HawkConst.LOGIN_COMPANY, company);
        Hawk.put(HawkConst.LOGIN_PASSWORD, password);
        stopLocationService();
        stopTrackerService();
        stopConfigService();

        FileUtil.clearDirs();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        App.getBus().removeStickyEvent(LoggedOutEvent.class);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onPhotoRequestedEvent(PhotoRequestedEvent event) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (event.getRequestCode()) {
            case Const.PHOTO_GALLERY:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.choose_image_title)), event.getRequestCode());
                break;
            case Const.PHOTO_CAMERA:
                intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileUtil.getOutputTempUri("images"));
                startActivityForResult(intent, event.getRequestCode());
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onFileViewRequestEvent(FileViewRequestEvent event) {
        File file = FileUtil.getFile(event.getEvent().getId());
        if (file == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.file_not_exists), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                String type = FileUtil.getMimeType(file.getPath());
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
                startActivity(intent);
                App.getBus().post(new FileViewedEvent(event.getEvent()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    App.getBus().post(new FileViewedEvent(event.getEvent()));
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.no_file_app), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onHideKeyboardEvent() {
        CommonUtil.hideKeyboard(this);
           }

    @Subscribe
    public void onMoveAppBackgroundEvent(MoveAppBackgroundEvent event) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case Const.PHOTO_GALLERY:
                    App.getBus().postSticky(new PhotoSelectedEvent(data.getData())); break;
                case Const.PHOTO_CAMERA:
                    Uri uri = FileUtil.renameFile(App.getConfigRepository().getPhotoMaxWidth());
                    App.getBus().postSticky(new PhotoSelectedEvent(uri)); break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Const.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    App.getBus().post(new PermissionGrantedEvent(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void runServices() {
        if (LocationUtil.isLocationEnabled(getBaseContext())) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                runLocationService();
            }
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.location_settings_disabled));
            dialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.go_to_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    App.getBus().post(new PageNavigateEvent(Const.APP_SETTINGS_LOCATION));
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        runTrackerService();
        runConfigService();
    }

    protected void runLocationService() {
        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }

    protected void stopLocationService() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    }

    protected void runTrackerService() {
        startService(new Intent(this, TrackerService.class));
    }

    protected void stopTrackerService() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, TrackerService.class));
    }

    protected void runConfigService() {
        startService(new Intent(this, ConfigService.class));
    }

    protected void stopConfigService() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, ConfigService.class));
    }

    protected boolean checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            App.getBus().post(new PermissionRequestedEvent(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void hideActionBar() {
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
    }

    private void createTabIcons(){
    }
}
```

And this is xml code for this activity .  activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="pl.eltegps.smokkomunikator.ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar_container">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I changed a code and put what you wriete but all the time i see a error

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya now I see this :     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.mutate()'

Comment: post full code here

Comment: it will be better if you share full code

Comment: post xml aloso here

Comment: @quicklearner I post xml code

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640563/how-do-i-change-a-tab-background-color-when-using-tablayout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562117/how-do-i-change-color-of-icon-of-the-selected-tab-of-tablayout/35330784

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I do what write a Nurcahyadin but it doesn't help me

Comment: follow this link for changing selected tab color http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611885/changing-the-background-color-of-a-tab-in-tablayout-android-design-support-libr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can set this color in xml only no need to write in code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorSplashBackground"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBottomLine">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

this will be the xml of tab layout and you have to pass your color in line

```
 app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorSplashBackground"
```